# Deleted Items not appearing in Trash folder. Stuck in .TRASH-1000

Tags: delete, trash, btrfs

I have a three 3TB discs in a BTRFS RAID 1 configuration mounted at /mnt/btrfs on my machine.
There is a symlink at /btrfs.

There are a number of subvols within this,

```
/archive
/backups
/games
/home
/music
/photos
/temp
/videos
/virtualmachines
```

/home is mounted at /mnt/btrfs/home/

When I delete an item from any folder in 'home' the items goes to the Recycle Bin correctly. I can recover and empty easily.

When I delete an item from any other subvol the object(s) go to .Trash-1000 within that subvol and this does not appear in my bin but has to be removed manually.

I suspect this is a permissions problem but cannot see what that could be.

Can anyone help with some suggestions for me?

Answer (score 4):

It is not a permissions problem.  This is a known bug which has been reported at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1442649 (it affects more than just Nautilus).

Except for the home filesystem which is a special case (see [here](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/trash-spec/trashspec-1.0.html) for full details), any trashed files are stored in a directory within the root directory of the filesystem they were deleted from, to avoid copying between filesystems.

The Trash folder is a virtual folder that *should* be a combination of those directories from every filesystem.

A subvolume is a separate filesystem. However, only *mount points* (e.g. those in `/etc/mtab`) are actually checked for trash directories.  A subvolume which is not mounted separately isn't searched.

As for workarounds, for a given subvolume SUBVOL, trying:

```
ln -s /mnt/btrfs/.Trash /mnt/btrfs/SUBVOL/.Trash
ln -s /mnt/btrfs/.Trash-1000 /mnt/btrfs/SUBVOL/.Trash-1000
```

to store the trash on the parent volume does not work.

But the existence of *both* symlinks (or just empty files of the same name) prevents the creation of the trash directories, so preventing trashing on that subvolume.

Comment: I'm also seeing the same problem, it's a real pain in the arse. I tried several ways of mounting the subvolumes to try and make Nautilus show the Trash correctly but something about btrfs subvolumes doesn't play nice. I ended up deleting manually all the `.Trash-100n` folders and then doing `sudo touch /home/$USER/<mount point>/.Trash-$UID` or similar for all the relevant btrfs subvolumes. This at least means nothing disappears into a hidden Trash and is forcibly deleted - not ideal but better than the alternative.